# React JS & Axios : How to post array of objects with axios form data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an endpoint that accept array of objects, but I don't know how to post the data based on user input using onChange. Here's my code

```
const [valuesInput, setValuesInput] = useState({
    title: "",
    question: [{ text: "", values: "" }],
    category: "",
  }); 

const data = new FormData();
data.append("feedback_title", valuesInput.title);
data.append("feedback_question", valuesInput.question);
data.append("kategori_feedback_id", valuesInput.category);

 <input key={c} type="text" onChange={(e) => {setValuesInput({...valuesInput,question: [
{text: e.target.value,values: e.target.value,},],});}} />
```

the things that I want to achieve are like this code :

```
"data": [
        {
            "pertanyaan_feedback_id": 1,
            "kategori_feedback_id": null,
            "feedback_title": "test",
            "feedback_question": [
                {
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-07-24T04:56:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-07-24T04:56:06.000000Z"
        }
```

are there any suggestion what should I do to post array of object based on my code above? I'm very thankful if you want to give soe advice to solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

I think when you feedback a product, you `post with NewFeedback function` include 2 or 3 fields `pertanyaan_feedback_id` and `feedback_title` or `kategori_feedback_id` if you need. After that, If have new a question, you go on `post with NewQuestion function` include 2 fields `text` and `values`

When `getAll` you have data such as expect

The last `data` have a `id` for `feedback_question` and `data`, that is very easy when update or delete.

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,                      // Add id
            "pertanyaan_feedback_id": 1,
            "kategori_feedback_id": null,
            "feedback_title": "test",
            "feedback_question": [
                {
                    "id": 1,              // Add id
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,              // Add id
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,              // Add id
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,              // Add id
                    "values": "dsfdsf",
                    "text": "vvfddf"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-07-24T04:56:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-07-24T04:56:06.000000Z"
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but i'm a little bit confused to add id in my array of objects..

Comment: Backend ? How language do you use. the `id` field auto creates for you.

Comment: i use laravel 8 for creating API. how can i do that? i have created "pertanyaan_feedback_id" as an id of pertanyaan_feedback table

Comment: `pertanyaan_feedback_id` as id => Ok. So, you add `id` in `feedback_question` => Ok too. And Font-end you can process as my suggest.

Comment: so how can i update my state using onChange in input reactjs?

Comment: If you have a minute, I can support for you. Let's add LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/linh-nguyen-96919a143/